# Substract rows in dataframes based on index pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
time    code    amount
2023-01 A   100000
2023-01 B   200000
2023-02 A   150000
2023-02 B   100000
```

I want to subtract base on index Time into:

```
code    amount
A   50000
B   -100000
```

Comment: hi Quang, can you give a more full example. This is great but there are many ways of getting the desired output

Comment: What is the logic? Can you have more than two dates? What would be the output?

Answer (score 1):

Group the dataframe by `code` and calculate the difference on `amount` column, and get rid of `NaN` values using `dropna`:

```py
>>> (df
 .groupby("code", as_index=True)
 .apply(lambda x: x["amount"].diff())
 .reset_index(level=0)
 .dropna()
 )

Out[1]: 
  code    amount
2    A   50000.0
3    B -100000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of getting the desired result:

```
df.assign(amount=df.groupby('code')['amount'].transform('diff')).dropna().drop('time', axis=1)
```